# want to build an iOS app that can send text messages to groups

Tags: ios, mobile, text, swift, sms

I'm learning Swift and newbie all together. I want to build an app I need.  I play a lot of tennis and have a network of men and women of around 50 or so at various skill levels.  I want to create an app that lets my network know I'm looking for a specific player, skill, day, time and I also want to see who is free or not. At the moment everything is done through texts, either sending a blast or text to each individual player. Players range from 18-60+ so not everyone uses facebook, etc, but I think having a tennis specific app could work.

Can I build an app that, when signed up, ***you'll be able to see who is available, and also send out alerts to the app OR as a text, when someone is looking for a player(s), or someone has made themselves available at a certain day or time slot***.  Also, if a text is received for those that do not have the app installed, the text response will notify the app and update their status.

Comment: Yes, you can. Everything is possible with sufficient time and money ;) (unless Apple doesn't want it to happen of course). However, by reading the question, i believe you believe it is much easier that it really is (you also will need a server).

Comment: Thank you, as I stated I am a newbie to this so I don't know what is or isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the quickest/easiest way to get started with this is using Parse ([parse.com](http://parse.com)) with push notifications. However, you should consider a simpler project for starting out, because this would still be a very complicated project.

Comment: Thank you, I will check parse out.  As for a simple project, can you see of anyway of taking this idea and simplifying it so I can still work on it but at a more simplistic version?  I'll also think about it, maybe just making an app that sends push notifications...I haven't done that yet.

Comment: Any app that is not contained solely on the device is significantly more complicated. I would recommend starting small and working up, e.g. start with a static listings app. Push notifications are cool, but they require some set up (developer account, certificates, push notification service etc).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will do that.  I'm using xCode by the way if that changes any part of my previous questions.

Comment: If you weren't using XCode I'd be very surprised.